# Почему Spring всегда подтягивает один и тот же конфиг?

Tags: java, spring

Есть  `DAO` слой и две его имплементации одна ведет к реальному `JDBC` драйверу, а вторая это стаб который хранит данные в памяти и используется в тестах. Для того что-бы тесты использовали имплементацию стаб класса я создал `test-config.xml` рядом с оригинальным `spring-context.xml`.

Но не смотря на то что в тестах я использую:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-config.xml");
```

Spring все рано ипользует основной конфиг. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем я ошибся, и как все таки настоить использование нужного файла конфигурации в тестах?

Пример теста:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-config.xml")
public class UserManagerTest {

    private final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-config.xml");

    private Item item = new Item(1, "test");

    @Test
    public void whenItemAddToDBThenDBContainItem() {

        final UserManager bean = context.getBean(UserManager.class);

        bean.add(item);

        final Item result = bean.get(1);

        assertThat(result, is(item));
    }
}
```

Сам конфигурационный файл:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans...

    <bean id="daoJdbc" class="ru.pravvich.dao.DAOMemory" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />
</beans>
```

И класс адаптер который использует эти `DAO` классы:

```
@Component
public class UserManager {

    private final DAO dao;

    @Autowired
    public UserManager(@Qualifier("DAOJdbc") final DAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

Сам `DAO` интерфейс:

```
public interface DAO {
    void add(Item item);
    Item getItem(int id);
}
```

Comment: 1. Покажи структуру всего проекта (интересует пакет `ru.pravvich`) 2. `@Qualifier("DAOJdbc")` - не видно четкого объявления (регистр важен). 3. У тебя странный тест, где нет runner'а и дважды объявлен один и тот же контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к вы пользуетесь аннотациями и для сканирования предоставили корень всего проекта (предположение по поводу base-package="ru.pravvich"), то

```
context.getBean(UserManager.class)
```

любой попавшийся бин. Или укажите имя бина, либо используйте xml кофигурацию и явно создайте нужный бин, и позже в тесте его получите